# How to change the color of the stock pagination that come with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I would like to change the **color** of the stock pagination that come with Laravel.

As default, it looks like this :

[image]

Let's say, I want to change it to green instead to match the theme of my web site.
Can someone tells me where I can change that ?

Comment: Did you try changing it; if yes, show what you tried.

Comment: Changing it is pretty simple, just change `class="primary"` to `class="success"`, but the problem is , I don't know where to change them in Laravel. That is it, that's my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to write some CSS rules that override the default bootstrap ones. Something like this would probably do:

```
.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
    color: green; // use your own color here
}

.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > span:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:hover {
    background-color: green;
    border-color: green;
}
```

---

If you don't want that, you need to create a [Custom Presenter](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#custom-presenters) that generates the pagination with the HTML code you want. You can have a look a the default Bootstrap Presenter that comes with Laravel to see how it's done, since what you'll need to implement will be very similar. The file is located here:

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/BootstrapPresenter.php

However **DO NOT** modify that file to apply your changes, because future updates can override your changes. Follow the instructions in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#custom-presenters) and create your own.

Comment: Good answer @Bogdan, although you forgot to set [color: white] in the active classes, otherwise the font color will stay the same as background and border color.

Answer (score 5):

to change color of active:

```css
.page-item.active .page-link {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: green; //your color
    border-color: green; //your color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    [aria-current] .page-link {
        background-color: red !important;
    }

    [rel='prev'], [rel='next'] {
        background-color: #0c85d0 !important;
    }

    .pagination > li :not([rel='prev'],[rel='next'],[aria-current] .page-link) {
        background-color: green !important;
    }
</style>
```